# Add existing Web Api project to existing Mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have two projects in my solution, a mvc project and a web api project. What is the best way to go about utilizing the web api project within the mvc application?

Options that I have come up with so far:

- Deploy both projects and use a helper class to interact with the api (javascript or server side)
- Add reference to web api project which adds api functionality to mvc project (not sure how to integrate api project into mvc project correctly, how would I do this?)

If there is a better alternative please share.

Comment: You can simplify everything by merging the projects. Include the web api controllers in your MVC project. There is no technical reason why this can't be done.

Comment: Divide the controller . In the folder Controllers retain the mvc controllers. Create a folder called ControllersApi and put the api in there.  Thers is no need to have two projects.

Comment: @Igor I don't necessarily want to combine the projects because there are distinct differences in the actual projects and the web api project would be consumed by other applications outside of the mvc project.

Comment: Then go for option 1. Deploy both projects and call the web api from script like you normally would. You will have to configure the domains correctly so you do not have any CORS issues but if you use subdomains this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder Controllers you have files like this:

```
namespace BeerDev.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And create another folder called ControllersApi with files like this:

```
namespace BeerDev.ControllersApi
{
    public class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            string beers;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/mockData/beerFront.json")))
            {
                beers = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(beers))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(beers);
        }
    }
}
```

In the Web Api project there is a specialized kind of controller, but still a controller.

You can refer to this [webAp2_example](https://github.com/psouki/BeerDev_WebApi2_version).

Answer (score 0):

If ASP.Net MVC application is the only one that consumes Web API, it is make sense to have them both inside a single project.

In my scenario, I have SPA using Angular, so I keep MVC and Web API controllers  in separate folders inside Controller folder.

The main advantage is that I can share models and class libraries. In addition, I do not have to worry about CORS.

[image]

### API Controller

Notice the **RoutePrefix**.

```
namespace MyApp.Web.Controllers.API
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/users")]
    public class UsersApiController : ApiController
    {
    }
}
```

### MVC Controller

```
namespace MyApp.Web.Controllers.MVC
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```